# Eclipse (android sdk intalled) crushed after update of yesterday

Tags: android, eclipse, logging

When I tried to open Eclipse, there was an error message "**An error has occurred. See the log file ...**".

And the log file content is :

```
1. !SESSION 2013-07-04 17:49:58.669
   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200 java.version=1.7.0_21
   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32,
   ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws
   win32 -arch x86

   !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 2 0 2013-07-04
   17:49:59.443 !MESSAGE [SCR] Found components with duplicated names!
   Details:  Component1 : Component[

    name = org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf     activate = activate
    deactivate = deactivate     modified =      configuration-policy =
optional    factory = null  autoenable = true   immediate = false
    implementation = 

org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.ECFTransportComponent
    state = Unsatisfied     properties =
{p2.agent.servicename=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.Transport}
    serviceFactory = false  serviceInterface =
[org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.spi.IAgentServiceFactory]  references =
null    located in bundle =
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf_1.0.100.v20120913-155635 [375]
]

Component2: Component[  name = org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf
    activate = activate     deactivate = deactivate     modified = 
    configuration-policy = optional     factory = null  autoenable = true
    immediate = false   implementation =
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.ECFTransportComponent
    state = Unsatisfied     properties =
{p2.agent.servicename=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.Transport}
    serviceFactory = false  serviceInterface =
[org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.spi.IAgentServiceFactory]  references =
null    located in bundle =
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf_1.0.100.v20120305-0333 [161] ] 


!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2013-07-04 17:50:01.667
!MESSAGE Unable to create class
'org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.CommandServiceAddon' from bundle '94'
!STACK 0 org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to
process "CommandServiceAddon#init()": no actual value was found for
the argument "IEclipseContext".     at
org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.reportUnresolvedArgument(InjectorImpl.java:396)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:858)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:113)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:321)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:255)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:185)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:49)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:557)  at
org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at
org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at
org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at
org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)    at
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)   at
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2013-07-04 17:50:01.677
!MESSAGE Unable to create class
'org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.CommandProcessingAddon'
from bundle '352' !STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process
"CommandProcessingAddon.commandService": no actual value was found
for the argument "ECommandService".     at
org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.reportUnresolvedArgument(InjectorImpl.java:396)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.resolveRequestorArgs(InjectorImpl.java:387)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:102)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:321)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:255)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:185)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:49)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:557)  at
org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at
org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at
org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at
org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)    at
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)   at
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2013-07-04 17:50:01.687
!MESSAGE Unable to create class
'org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon' from
bundle '355' !STACK 0 org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException:
Unable to process "BindingProcessingAddon.commandService": no actual
value was found for the argument "ECommandService".     at
org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.reportUnresolvedArgument(InjectorImpl.java:396)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.resolveRequestorArgs(InjectorImpl.java:387)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:102)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:321)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:255)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:185)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:49)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:557)  at
org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at
org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at
org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at
org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)    at
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)   at
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-07-04 17:50:01.829 !MESSAGE One or
more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints
are not resolved: !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-07-04
17:50:01.829 !MESSAGE Bundle
reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.100.v20120521-2346/
was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2
org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry 2 0 2013-07-04
17:50:01.829 !MESSAGE Missing required capability
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;
filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-07-04 17:50:01.829 !MESSAGE The
following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see
the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists: !SUBENTRY 1
org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-07-04 17:50:01.829 !MESSAGE Bundle
org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.100.v20120521-2346
[89] was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2
org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry 2 0 2013-07-04
17:50:01.829 !MESSAGE Missing required capability
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;
filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-07-04 17:50:01.829 !MESSAGE
Bundle org.eclipse.ui.win32_3.2.300.v20120820-200440 [261] was not
resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-07-04 17:50:01.829 !MESSAGE
Application error !STACK 1

java.lang.NullPointerException  at 

org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.processHierarchy(E4Workbench.java:172)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.init(E4Workbench.java:118)
    at
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.<init>(E4Workbench.java:69)
    at
```

What should I do? Please help!

Comment: check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16603961/2345913)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly figuring out and fixing this problem will take a lot more time than just downloading the [android developer tools again](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). It's eclipse with the plugins pre-bundled so you shouldn't have to worry about stuff like this.